# Match multiple rows of same column using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have following data.

```
00001*  FI  SN3623  FO  SN3624 OOSSD*   10.06.2015* 1.00*   154,00* 0*
     *   WO 74985                    *
```

I want to select this data using a regex expression:

`FI  SN3623  FO  SN3624 OOSSD WO 74985`

Is it possible? How?
The data is in tabular format in text file. I want to extract data from second column as one group. * represents next column.
      *   WO 74985                    * this data is on second line. But I still want to select it in the group with data of first row second column.
In short I want data of first row second column and second row second column together.

Comment: Please format your code, this is unreadable.

Comment: Well- care to explain on what criteria we should select these values?

Comment: Is your data fixed width/length? You may not need regex at all in that case

Comment: Please consider reading *what Regex really is* first. Using `split(" ")` function is probably a better choice here.

Comment: You can experiment with http://rubular.com/

Comment: You can match the second column easily, however you can not merge the matches. If you need that, then you will need to concatenate them in your program with string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do it, if you really want to use regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*?\\*\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\*.*[\r\n]+.*?\\*\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\*").matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Andreas this is what I wanted. Thank you so much.